# How to access FragmentManager in Service?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-service

I am creating something like Facebook Chat Heads, and I need to have access to FragmentManager in Service. Many people would say that I can't do that, but there always is a way, so I ask you guys, how can I access FragmentManager from Service?

In my Service, in `onCreate` method I have:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, null);
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.pager);

FragmentManager fm = [HOW CAN I ACCESS THIS?];

pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(fm));
```

Comment: it is not possible to get the FragmentManager in service

Comment: @Damian how you solved your issue? Please share your code, struck with same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to have access to FragmentManager in Service

Not only is that not possible, but you do not need it. There is nothing in Android that can *only* be accomplished via fragments.

For example, you appear to be using a `ViewPager`. You do not need to use fragments with a `ViewPager`. In fact, a `ViewPager` itself has nothing to do with fragments. The two concrete `PagerAdapter` implementations (`FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) happen to use fragments. But it is perfectly possible to create a `PagerAdapter` implementation of your own that does not use fragments. And, it will take you substantially less time to implement a `PagerAdapter` that works with `Views` than it will to somehow cram a `FragmentManager` -- tied inextricably to the activity lifecycle -- into a `Service`.

Comment: Thank you very much, not having to create fragments saved me :)

Comment: @Commons , I don't think your point is valid in all situations. For example if I want to have google maps in a service, I cannot have that. Now you might think why do I need google maps in a service. Thats because I am developing a keyboard app which has no activity and there I want a functionality of the google maps which need getFragmentManager().

Comment: @DEEPANKURSADANA: You are welcome to try to [use `MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

Comment: It's entirely reasonable to want to access FragmentManager in a Service or Application (with Context but without an Activity) in order to use enableDebugLogging() (for instance). Not knowing a valid reason for a Question doesn't mean that the question isn't valid.

Comment: @Graeme: "It's entirely reasonable to want to access FragmentManager in a Service or Application" -- not really. "in order to use enableDebugLogging()" -- since the documentation does not state the scope of the effects of that method, you should assume that it only affects the specific instance of `FragmentManager` that you call it on. Hence, you should call it for the `FragmentManager` instance from each activity (and fragment, if you use nested fragments).

Comment: And using ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in an Application gives you that chance. Again, because you don't know a valid reason, doesn't mean a valid reason does not exist outside your scope of knowledge.

Comment: @Graeme: "And using ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in an Application gives you that chance" -- correct. That is not related to the question to which I answered. In your case, the `Application` does not have its own `FragmentManager`. Nor does a service or any other non-activity/fragment class. The question is about showing a UI directly from a service ("something like Facebook Chat Heads"), which cannot be accomplished using fragments, as services do not have fragments.

Comment: I need fragmentManager because I want to call a dialogFragment from service.

Comment: @Starwave: You can't call a `DialogFragment` from a `Service`, sorry.

Answer (score -4):

In your main_activity declare and Initialize Fragment Manager as static;

```
public static FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    fm = getFragmentManager();

}
```

fm variable can be used in service.